# Create Azure Devops/Pipeline release including all meta data like buildNumber via REST

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-devops-rest-api

I'am aware of https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/releases/create?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0#uri-parameters and i can create releases via REST, but ...

**Problem:**
The issue with those releases is, that a release triggered via the REST lacks some predefined variables like `Build.BuildNumber` - or at least, they are not available at all scopes.

It seems like `Build.BuildNumber` is available in the `pipeline stage`, but is missing in when the *release name format* is computed. This means, a *release name format* `Release-$(Build.BuildNumber)($(Release.ReleaseId))` will end up with a blank `Build.BuildNumber` when created using the payload below.

**Details:**

My json payload

```json
{
  "definitionId": 9,
  "description": "Test Release",
  "artifacts": [
    {
      "alias": "My Build Artifact",
      "instanceReference": {
        "id": "6989",
        "name": null
      }
    }
  ],
  "isDraft": false,
  "reason": "none",
  "manualEnvironments": null
}
```

While `artifacts.instanceReference.id` references a valid build (which of course has a buildNumber) - so that during the release stage `Build.BuildNumber` is properly populated.

I send the payload via

```sh
curl -X POST -u username:redactedPAT -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d @payload.json https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/redactedCompany/redactedProjectId/_apis/release/releases\?api-version\=6.0
```

**Question:**
What is the right way to create a release as if this would be created via the GUI including all the META-Data?
Do i miss use the API somehow or do i need to manually set the environment variables for this to work (or even somehow via `variables`).
Since the `buildNumber` is available in the stage, could that be rather/even a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The release name is evaluated at the compile time, which means it is populated before the pipeline tasks are executed. You can check out below workarounds to populated the release name.

1, The `$(Build.BuildNumber)` variable you defined in the release name format will retrieve the `name` property you pass to the `artifacts` `instanceReference` in the request body. So you can pass the BuildNumber value to the `name` property under `instanceReference` in the request body. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/releases/create?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0#buildversion).

```
{
  ...
  "artifacts": [
    {
      "alias": "My Build Artifact",
      "instanceReference": {
        "id": "6989",
        "name": BuildNumber #set the buildNumber here.
      }
    }
  ],
  ...
}
```

2, Another workaround is to use [logging commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/logging-commands?view=azure-devops&tabs=bash#release-commands) to update the release name in a script task.

You can add a script task in your release pipeline stage. And run below logging command to update the release name during the release pipeline execution.

`echo "##vso[release.updatereleasename]Release-$(Build.BuildNumber)($(Release.ReleaseId))"`

See below example:

[image]

When the task is executed. it will update the release name with your desired format.

Comment: Adding an extra step in the stage is nothing i would like to desire, but using 'name' to set the build name works for me, eventhough it feels very counter intuitive having a key "name" of a release, which then maps to the release number :)